# React page layout using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a default layout page here using react router:

```
Header = require('./components/Header'),
Footer = require('./components/Footer'),


var sampleApp= React.createClass({

getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      title: 'Page One'
    };
},    

render: function (){
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <Header title={this.props.title} />
            <RouteHandler />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
},

});

var routes = (
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={sampleApp}>
    <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={HomePage}  />
    <Route name="add-school" handler={AddPage}  />
</Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function(Handler){
var mountNode = document.getElementById('app');
React.render(<Handler /> , mountNode);
});
```

Am I able to pass the page title into the header component above? Here is one of pages, with the title set in default props.

```
var HomePage = React.createClass({

mixins: [Router.Navigation],

getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      // set page title here
      title: 'Page Two'
    };
},

getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        tiles: null
    }
},
```

The page title doesnt show and stays as the default 'page one' in the layout. Can anyone please tell me how I can pass props up to the header component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a component like [react-document-title](https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title) to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, how do I configure it to use with my header component?

Comment: Just wrap your header render function with a DocumentTitle tag. Look at examples in the library documentation.

Comment: Sorry for the down-vote, but the question here is not about setting dynamically the page title in the html's <head> tag, but about communicating between components that are not children / parents.